# Why Android Lint can't catch a casting error?

Tags: android, casting, lint

Here is my a.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/true_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/false_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pre_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pre_image"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_image"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my A.java

```
    package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private ImageButton mPreButton;
    private ImageButton mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;
    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";
    private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";

    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_midease, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.quesion_asia, true) };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
        boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

        int messageResId = 0;

        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void updateQuestion() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Updating question text for question #" + mCurrentIndex, new Exception());
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
        outState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX);
        }

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mQuestionTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
            //Lint should be catch the error at here
        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        Log.i(TAG , mQuestionTextView.getClass().getName()) ;
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
            }
        });
        mPreButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pre_button);
        mPreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex +mQuestionBank.length-1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        mNextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });

        updateQuestion();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The code will attempt to cast a TextView as a Button at runtime.

Lint has to catch this error and warn. (i.e. Unexpected cast to Buton ...)

But my Lint shows nothing.

WHY?

Comment: There's the `WrongViewCast` lint rule that catches some errors of this kind. But it probably has it bugs and limitations - can you post a more complete example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "Lint has to catch" ... why? Lint catches only a limited number of errors. Maybe you can add a feature request to Google, this is an error that can be somewhat common.

Comment: @laalto Edited for reproduce.